# Flink: Why is Hive dependency flink-sql-connector-hive not available on Maven Central?

Tags: maven, hive, apache-flink

According to [Flink SQL Hive: Using bundled hive jar](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/connectors/hive/#using-bundled-hive-jar):

> The following tables list all available bundled hive jars. You can pick one to the /lib/ directory in Flink distribution.
>
> - flink-sql-connector-hive-1.2.2 (download link)
> - flink-sql-connector-hive-2.2.0 (download link)
>   ...

However, these dependencies are not available from Maven central. As a work around, I use [user defined dependencies](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/connectors/hive/#user-defined-dependencies), but this is not recommended:

> the recommended way to add dependency is to use a bundled jar. Separate jars should be used only if bundled jars don’t meet your needs.

I wonder why the bundle jars are not available in Maven central?

Follow-up: Since they are not available from Maven central, I wonder how to include them in pom.xml in order to run `mvn package`, if I don't want to use user defined dependencies?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is, I am wrong. flink-sql-connector-hive does exist in maven central, see https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-sql-connector-hive-2.2.0_2.11/1.12.0/jar.